# How to set config for Fastify route config when using NestJS

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-fastify

There is an option to set route config in Fastify like:

https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Routes/#config

```
fastify.get('/en', { config: { output: 'hello world!' } }, handler)
```

but is there an option to set config when using NestJS with Fastify?

```
  // where to put config for route 
  @Post('/en')
  async createResource(
    @Body() payload: any,
  ): Promise<void> {}
```